# What are the flaws in my algorithm to insert a node in a function tree?

Tags: c, algorithm, parsing, data-structures, tree

I'm working on an algorithm that builds a tree out of a math function. For example:

```
x^2+5*3
```

gets built to

```
     /   +    \
    /          \
  / ^ \      / * \
  x   2     5     3
```

The nodes of the tree are objects

```
typedef struct node
{
    char * fx; // function
    struct node * gx; // left-hand side
    char * op; // operator
    struct node * hx; // right-hand side
} node;
```

so that the above tree would actually be like

```
                            (root node)
                      { 0, / , '+',  \   }
                          /           \
                         /             \
                        /               \
                       /                 \
                      /                   \
   { 0, / , '^', \ }                        { 0, / , '*', \ }
       /          \                             /          \
      /            \                           /            \
     /              \                         /              \
    /                \                       /                \
{"x", 0, 0, 0}     {"2", 0, 0, 0}         {"5", 0, 0, 0}    {"3", 0, 0, 0}
```

The function I'm having trouble with is the one that inserts a new node in the tree. For example, if the tree that has been built so far is

```
  / ^ \
 /     \
x       2
```

and I've just found the operator `+` and the number `5` following it, I need to rebuild the tree to

```
       /   +   \
      /         \
   / ^ \         5
  /     \
 x       2
```

The function I'm attempting to do that with looks like

```
void insertInTree ( node * * curRootPtr, char * newOp, node * newNode )
{
    //    crpp: Pointer to a pointer to the node element that is the current root
    //   newOp: New operator found
    // newNode: New node corresponding to the expression following the operator

    node * rightTraveler = *curRootPtr;
    while (!0)
    {
        if (rightTraveler->op)
        {
            long thisOpIdx = strchr(opstack, *rightTraveler->op) - opstack;
            long newOpIdx = strchr(opstack, *newOp) - opstack;
            if (thisOpIdx > newOpIdx) break; // if new operator has a lower precendence than the
                                             // operator on the current node,
            rightTraveler = rightTraveler->hx;
        }
        else // reached a node that has no children
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    node * temp = rightTraveler;
    rightTraveler = malloc(sizeof(node));
    rightTraveler->gx = temp; rightTraveler->op = newOp; rightTraveler->hx = newNode;
}
```

where `opstack` is defined by

```
char opstack [] = {'+','-','*','^'}; // operators, with precedence sorted from lowest to highest
```

For some reason, though, this function isn't working. It is not rebuilding the tree at all. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Where are you connecting the newly malloc-ed rightTraveler with its parent in the existing tree?

Comment: At the point of the line `node * temp = rightTraveler;`, the `rightTraveler` is the node that will get replaced. A copy of it becomes the left-hand side of its newly instantiated self in the statement `rightTraveler->gx = temp;`

Comment: But rightTraveler's original parent is now temp's parent. In fact temp ends up having two parents, one rightTraveler's original parent in the tree and the other newly-malloced rightTraveler. The new rightTraveler does not seem to have any parent.

Comment: IMO to insert a new node, you will have to stop traversing the tree one step earlier so that you have access to the new node's parent.

Comment: It may make the whole thing easier to deal with the tree recursively. The logic clears it's up when developing. In support of comment by user199...,  it often makes sense to cache the parent when traversing a single direction structure like your tree or a linked list. Always initialise cache to NULL as the first node has no parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wbhat you are doing is logically incorrect. Consider the following snippet:

> ```
> node * temp = rightTraveler;//currently rightTraveler is the rightmost leaf node, say R, accessible from some node, say X(may be null)
> rightTraveler = malloc(sizeof(node)); //rightTraveler is newly assigned 
> rightTraveler->gx = temp; //temp is R, now accessible from new rightTraveller and from X
> rightTraveler->op = newOp; //assignes values to new node
> rightTraveler->hx = newNode;
> ```

so what you are doing is inserting a node between X and R while still maintaining the connection between X and R, so, in your printTree function, it is traversing through the link between X and R and it prints the same. That is why you get the illusion that the tree is not being rebuilt.

The solution is to break the connection between X and R and link X with the newNode. In your while loop, stop **just before** the leaf node and then change that node's ->gx variable to newNode